# How to: Ninject Bindings (Unit Of Work, Factories and Services)

Tags: ninject, unit-of-work

A little background on the issue:  In the wild I see a lot of Services that are dependent on some implementation of IUnitOfWork.  When I examine the ninject binding for these applications, I notice they are pretty simple because there is typically only one binding for the IUnitOfWork.

My application unfortunately has to have 2 bindings for IUnitOfWork.  Services A and B will use a unit of work which points to our Staging database, and Services C and D will use a unit of work that is pointing to our Production database.

I'm able to do this right now by setting up named bindings for Services A and B, and then creating bindings for IUnitOfWork like so:

```
Kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>()
            .To<StagingUnitOfWork>
            .WhenParentNamed("ServiceA")

kernel.Bind<IServiceA>()
            .To<ServiceA>
            .Named("ServiceA")
```

However, I don't like how I'm going to have to create another binding for IUnitOfWork for "ServiceB".  Do I just need to "suck it up" and use this approach?

Note: I'd like to keep my classes clean of injection attributes, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is the only approach you've got.

```
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<StagingUnitOfWork>().WhenInjectedInto<ServiceA>();
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<StagingUnitOfWork>().WhenInjectedInto<ServiceB>();
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<ProductionUnitOfWork>().WhenInjectedInto<ServiceC>();
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<ProductionUnitOfWork>().WhenInjectedInto<ServiceD>();
```

Comment: I tend to agree this is one of the only options I've found as well.  I'm going to go ahead and give the answer to you.